# Error SpringBoot Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join

Tags: java, mysql, path

I have reviewed the other articles that discuss this issue but doesn't resolve mine.
The following query:

```
package com.cyberguard.webservice.course;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface CourseRepository extends JpaRepository<Course, String> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT Course_ID, Course_Name FROM Course c JOIN major_courses mc ON c.Course_ID = mc.Course_ID JOIN Major m ON mc.ID = m.ID WHERE m.ID = ?1")
    List<Course> findByMajors(Long major);
}
```

Outputs this error. Previous to this, I had no problem. Basically, I'm trying to find courses related to a specific major. The relationship between the major class and course is Many to Many thus having a linking table.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'courseController' defined in file [C:\Users\arahi\Documents\GitHub\CyberguardCourseRegistration\webservice\target\classes\com\cyberguard\webservice\course\CourseController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'courseService' defined in file [C:\Users\arahi\Documents\GitHub\CyberguardCourseRegistration\webservice\target\classes\com\cyberguard\webservice\course\CourseService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'courseRepository' defined in com.cyberguard.webservice.course.CourseRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.cyberguard.webservice.course.CourseRepository.findByMajors(java.lang.Long)! Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.cyberguard.webservice.course.CourseRepository.findByMajors(java.lang.Long)!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.cyberguard.webservice.course.CourseRepository.findByMajors(java.lang.Long)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at com.cyberguard.webservice.WebserviceApplication.main(WebserviceApplication.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'courseService' defined in file [C:\Users\arahi\Documents\GitHub\CyberguardCourseRegistration\webservice\target\classes\com\cyberguard\webservice\course\CourseService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'courseRepository' defined in com.cyberguard.webservice.course.CourseRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.cyberguard.webservice.course.CourseRepository.findByMajors(java.lang.Long)! Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.cyberguard.webservice.course.CourseRepository.findByMajors(java.lang.Long)!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.cyberguard.webservice.course.CourseRepository.findByMajors(java.lang.Long)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'courseRepository' defined in com.cyberguard.webservice.course.CourseRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.cyberguard.webservice.course.CourseRepository.findByMajors(java.lang.Long)! Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.cyberguard.webservice.course.CourseRepository.findByMajors(java.lang.Long)!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.cyberguard.webservice.course.CourseRepository.findByMajors(java.lang.Long)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.cyberguard.webservice.course.CourseRepository.findByMajors(java.lang.Long)! Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.cyberguard.webservice.course.CourseRepository.findByMajors(java.lang.Long)!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.cyberguard.webservice.course.CourseRepository.findByMajors(java.lang.Long)!
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException.create(QueryCreationException.java:101) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:106) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1056) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:86) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:86) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:360) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:323) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:230) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:329) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.cyberguard.webservice.course.CourseRepository.findByMajors(java.lang.Long)!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:93) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:63) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:76) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:56) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:146) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:216) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:81) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:102) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    ... 66 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join! [SELECT Course_ID, Course_Name FROM com.cyberguard.webservice.course.Course c JOIN major_courses mc ON c.Course_ID = mc.Course_ID JOIN com.cyberguard.webservice.major.Major m ON mc.ID = m.ID WHERE m.ID = ?1]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:734) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:362) ~[spring-orm-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy96.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:87) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    ... 73 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join! [SELECT Course_ID, Course_Name FROM com.cyberguard.webservice.course.Course c JOIN major_courses mc ON c.Course_ID = mc.Course_ID JOIN com.cyberguard.webservice.major.Major m ON mc.ID = m.ID WHERE m.ID = ?1]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker.throwQueryException(ErrorTracker.java:93) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:282) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:613) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:725) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    ... 81 common frames omitted
```

The following is my Course.java file:

```
package com.cyberguard.webservice.course;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.cyberguard.webservice.major.Major;


@Entity
@Table(name = "courses")
public class Course {
    @Id
    private String Course_ID;
    
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "courses")
    Set<Major> Majors = new HashSet<>();
    
    private String Course_Section;
    private String Course_Name;
    
    
    public Course() {
        
    }
    
    public Course(String id, String courseSection, String courseName) {
        this.Course_ID = id;
        this.Course_Section = courseSection;
        this.Course_Name = courseName;
        System.out.println("Success");
    }

    public String getCourse_ID() {
        return Course_ID;
    }

    public void setCourse_ID(String course_ID) {
        Course_ID = course_ID;
    }

    public Set<Major> getMajors() {
        return Majors;
    }

    public void setMajors(Set<Major> majors) {
        this.Majors = majors;
    }

    public String getCourse_Section() {
        return Course_Section;
    }

    public void setCourse_Section(String course_Section) {
        Course_Section = course_Section;
    }

    public String getCourse_Name() {
        return Course_Name;
    }

    public void setCourse_Name(String course_Name) {
        Course_Name = course_Name;
    }


    
    
    
    

}
```

Comment: Is that number 1 in `WHERE m.ID = ?1` a typo that causes this?

Comment: No that's simply to say that's the first parameter. I already found the answer, look at the comment I posted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My professor just answered it! I just needed to add a second parameter to my query with the following

```
nativeQuery = true
```

The following is the right way to write the query:

```
package com.cyberguard.webservice.course;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface CourseRepository extends JpaRepository<Course, String> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT c.Course_ID, c.Course_Name FROM courses c JOIN 
major_courses mc ON c.Course_ID = mc.Course_ID JOIN majors m ON mc.ID = m.ID WHERE m.ID = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Course> findByMajors(Long major);
}
```